# How do I calculate the latency time of a hard disk?

Tags: latency, hard-drive

So for example, a hard disk rotates with 5400 RPM, while the arm needs 4 ms to move from track 1 to track 80. And I am looking for the worst case sector access time (in ms).

So i'm aware the sum is simply "X ms (in this case 4) seek time + X latency time = ANS".

But i'm struggling to come to grasps with how to calculate the latency. I seen from searching online that "Latency = 0.5 rev on average = X ms for an X RPM disk" but this makes no sense to me. Can anyone simplify this?

Comment: You found online the average latency time, but want to know on your side the worst latency time, so your latency time on track will be 60s/5400rpm or 1s/(5400/60)rps  as the disc rotates 5400 times in one minute. If i calclulated correctly, this should be 11ms

Comment: BTW, the average is calculated from the worst and best access time on track, so best would be immediately after the track is spotted, and the sector is under the head -> 0ms. but when the sector just passed under the head, you need to wait a full rotation of the disc. Given the average over time, this will be half of the time it takes to rotate the disc one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the type and brand ? Your RPM is 5400, so you have 5400/60 = 90 rotations per second, taking 11ms per rotation. The opposite side -worst case- is reached in 11/2 is 5.5ms.

https://sciencing.com/calculate-rotational-latency-8559684.html

But.. you are talking *seek* time.. the real life answer does not solely depend on the RPM of the disk. The real worst case head travel will require the head itself to go inward or outward. Max angular distance **and** max radius travel. So it also depends on the travel time the head needs to move inward.

https://theithollow.com/2013/11/18/disk-latency-concepts/

[http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSFEP/file-disks.pdf](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSFEP/file-disks.pdf)

Tip: google your disk brand and/or serial number. You'll find a fact sheet.

Comment: Does the head always move from track say 20 to track 0 before moving to track 25? Would be a bad performance, so the maximum track seek time is (as TO posted) 4ms, from track 0 to track 80...

Comment: Guess it will not move back on every seek ! driver and firmware of the harddisk should optimize things like that. Aside loss of speed, minimizing the heads move must be done, to prolong the life time of your mechanics ! But honestly.. I don't really know if there is a difference between types and how often a "homing move" back to 0 is required.. For other equipment I work with, a "homing move" is only needed when the set point is lost, or a following error occurs, or when the head comes back from a parking position. That could happen. It is 5400 RpM, so the disk in this question is quite old.